# X-Sendfile notification after finish download

Tags: php, x-sendfile

I would need to set the download status to 0 when download has finished. I am using x-sendfile, but after finish download, dont set status.

My code:

```
header("X-Sendfile: $file");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');

mysql_query("UPDATE `downloads` SET `download_status` = '1' WHERE `id` = '" . $last_down . "'");
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Liska - welcome to SO!

Comment: Hi Tomáš, have you found any solution to you question?

Comment: Hi, I not found anything correct :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't detect when the client finished downloading the file if you using X-Sendfile.
Simplest way is stream file by script.

```
$handle = fopen($filepath, 'rb');
if ($handle !== false) {
    @flock($handle, LOCK_SH);

    $size = filesize($filepath);
    $filename = basename($filepath);
    $old_max_execution_time = ini_get('max_execution_time');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    $old_cache_limiter = session_cache_limiter();
    session_cache_limiter(false);

    if (ob_get_length()) ob_clean();
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'. $filename .'"');
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Pragma: private');
    set_time_limit(0);
    while (! feof($handle) && (connection_status() === 0)) {
        if (! $buffer = @fread($handle, $interval)) {
            // Error
            exit;
        }

        print($buffer);
        flush();
    }
    @flock($handle, LOCK_UN);
    @fclose($handle);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', $old_max_execution_time);
    session_cache_limiter($old_cache_limiter);

    // ----------------------------------------------------
    // Downloading complete!
    // Here you can update your table row in DB...
    // ----------------------------------------------------

    exit;
}
```